# cbind specific columns in list (without dplyr package)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, cbind

I have a list with approximately 50 (slots) - *dataframes*.  Each and every *element* of this list (*dataframe*) has 10 columns, 3 of which correspond to "year", "month" and "day". How can I cbind those three columns into one (by creating new column), in every dataframe of this list, and convert them at the same time to *as.Date* format **without using the dplyr package** .

I'm sending a reproducible example:

```
city_A <- data.frame(year = c(1995,1996,1997),month = c(5,6,9),day = c(1,5,8),ozone = c(0.5,0.9,0.12))
city_D <- data.frame(year = c(1982,1959,1909),month = c(3,10,12),day = c(21,24,30),ozone = c(1.5,2.9,3.14))

town_list <- list(city_A,city_D)
```

The expected outcome is something like this:

```
[[1]]
  date              year   month day  ozone
1 1995-05-01        1995     5     1    0.5
2 1996-06-05        1996     6     5    0.9
3 1997-09-08        1997     9     8    0.12

[[2]]
  date              year   month day  ozone
1 1982-03-21        1982     3    21    1.5
2 1959-10-24        1959    10    24    2.9
3 1909-12-30        1909    12    30    3.14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ISOdate` to `transform` to create the `Date` class

```
lapply(town_list, transform, date = as.Date(ISOdate(year, month, day)))
```

---

If it  needs to be the first column, either `cbind` or use column indexing afterwards

```
lapply(town_list, \(x) 
    cbind(date = with(x, as.Date(ISOdate(year, month, day))), x))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `do.call(rbind, x)`

```r
city_A <- data.frame(year = c(1995,1996,1997),month = c(5,6,9),day = c(1,5,8),ozone = c(0.5,0.9,0.12))
city_D <- data.frame(year = c(1982,1959,1909),month = c(3,10,12),day = c(21,24,30),ozone = c(1.5,2.9,3.14))

town_list <- list(city_A,city_D)

do.call(rbind, town_list)
#>   year month day ozone
#> 1 1995     5   1  0.50
#> 2 1996     6   5  0.90
#> 3 1997     9   8  0.12
#> 4 1982     3  21  1.50
#> 5 1959    10  24  2.90
#> 6 1909    12  30  3.14
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>